# How to have a large file in heroku server

Tags: java, eclipse, heroku, jax-rs

We have a RESTful web service on Heroku and we have a 100mb "vectors.bin" file on src/main folder in our eclipse-workspace. I can access the path of the file like this in my local Tomcat environment:

```
kNNClassifier classifier = new kNNClassifier(new Word2Vec((PollsInterface.class.getClassLoader().getResource("vectors.bin")).getPath().substring(1)), 8);
```

This results: "Z:/Dropbox/SYNC/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/webdevelopment/WEB-INF/classes/vectors.bin"

But when I deploy on Heroku, at the code line above, it returns 500 internal exception on browser, basically it cannot do it.

I checked with Amazon S3 service to use but how do I use a file in my src main folder, is it impossible?

Answer (score 0):

In order to access the file with `getClassLoader().getResource("vectors.bin")`, it will need to be on the classpath. I suspect`src/main` is not on your class path on Heroku. You can add it by putting the file in the `-cp` option of your Java command.